# Не работают события MouseLeftButtonDown/Up между разными ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

У меня есть View с `ListBox`:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LB1}" Height="270">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Content}"
                           Background="BlanchedAlmond">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.MLBD, 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                        AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}, 
                                        Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.MLBU, 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                        AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}, 
                                        Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding LB2}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Content}"
                           Background="BlanchedAlmond">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.MLBD, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                    AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}, 
                                    Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.MLBU, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                    AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}, 
                                    Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

И ViewModel с реализацией событий MouseLeftButtonDown/Up для обмена `Content` между `ListBoxItem`

```
    public List<Label> LB1 { get; set; }
    public List<Label> LB2 { get; set; }

    public Label Swap { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        LB1 = new List<Label>()
        {
            new Label() { Content="10"},
            new Label() { Content="20"},
            new Label() { Content="30"}
        };
        LB2 = new List<Label>()
        {
            new Label() { Content="01"},
            new Label() { Content="02"},
            new Label() { Content="03"}
        };

        Swap = new Label();
    }


    public Command<Label> MLBD => new Command<Label>((label) =>
    {
        Swap = label;
    });

    public Command<Label> MLBU => new Command<Label>((label) =>
    {
        string text = label.Content.ToString();
        label.Content = Swap.Content;
        Swap.Content = text;
    });
```

В пределах о одного `ListBox` всё работает нормально, но когда `MouseLeftButtonDown` делаю в одном `ListBox` а `MouseLeftButtonUp` в другом то событие `MouseLeftButtonUp` не срабатывает. А если `MouseLeftButtonUp` сделать в месте где нет контролов а потом на другой `ListBox` то обмен происходит, хотя так быть не должно.

Подскажите как исправить ситуацию. Всё делал в Catel с использованием Fody.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось проблема в том что `ListBox` автоматически делает захват мыши, для решения добавляем следующий обработчик `MouseLeave` для `Label`:

```
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.CaptureOff, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                    Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
```

и сама логика:

```
    public Command CaptureOff => new Command(() =>
    {
        Mouse.Capture(null);
    });
```